# Можно ли поменять стиль отправляемого в Telegram-бота текста?

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram, шрифты

Создаю своего первого telegram-бота. Использую их библиотеку TelegramBotsAPI. Посылку сообщений уже наладил, в целом все работает, но хочется, чтобы все было по красоте, а именно стилизацию шрифтов. Чтобы, например, одна часть текста в сообщении выводилась жирным, а другая - курсивом.

Подскажите, насколько это вообще реализуемо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого в Telegram API у класса `SendMessage` есть метод `setParseMode()`, который позволяет установить тип разметки. Например `ParseMode.HTML` позволит форматировать текст с помощью html-тегов. То есть просто у вашего объекта `SendMessage` вызовите вышеуказанный метод и дальше в тексте сообщения применяйте нужные теги, например вот так: `<b>жирный шрифт</b>`  `<i>курсив</i>`. Также вы можете использовать `ParseMode.MARKDOWN`, в этом случае подобное форматирование текста будет выглядеть так: `**жирный шрифт**`  `*курсив*`. Однако это форматирование имеет некоторые ограничения, поэтому лучше всего ознакомиться с [документацией](https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#formatting-options)